# factory_girl_rails: factory built model instance's has_many association not populated when an associated child is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, factory-bot

I'm using [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) instead of fixtures. Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :project
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Here's the relevant factory:

```
Factory.define :task do |t|
  t.association :user
  t.association :project
  t.after_create {|t| t.user.tasks << t}
  t.after_create {|t| t.project.tasks << t}
end
```

In an integration test I do this:

```
scenario "user with tasks from one project is assigned another task from the same project" do
  user = Factory.create :user
  (1..5).each { Factory.create(:task, :user => user, :project => user.project)}
  visit_project_path user.project
  correctly_fill_in_new_task_fields
  click_button "Create task" #creates a new task for the above user
  assert user.tasks.size == 6 #currently fails
end
```

The problem that I have is that after the scenario runs `user.tasks.size == 5`, but `Task.where(:user_id => user.id).size == 6`. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is more likely due to the way ActiveRecord works.  Your controller fetches the user from the database and creates *a new instance of User*.  Now your controller and your test have references to two different users, which is why your test never sees the changes.

You'll need to call `reload` on `user` before checking how many tasks there are again.

Side-note: some ORMs provide an identity map (special type of registry) to get around this problem (actually... a quick Google seems to indicate Rails 3 recently got an Identity Map added to the source.  I don't use AR, so not sure how you enable it).